# Git branching and reset head of master

Tags: git, git-branch

Git

Step -1: I made few un-commit changes to master branch at local machine.

Step -2: Later i decided to create separate branch for those changes because i notice these changes are much bigger and has become a feature.

Step -3: I created a branch switch to that branch made my changes.

Step 04: Now i want to merge my newly created branch to master, but i still had few un-commit in master, i tried to reset hard my origin/master branch and my all newly branch changes and master branch changes are gone :(

I also noticed what ever changes i was making in newly created branch they were also appearing in master branch.

I thought local branch and master are unsync branches. please help me to understand the concept that why did that happen.

Comment: Could you provide the git commands that you used to do this please because I'm a bit unclear of what you did here. If you created a branch from master with uncommitted changes then the changes would be uncommitted on the new branch.

Comment: Did you commit between step 03 and step 04?

Comment: yes commit my changes into newly created branch b/w steps 03 and 04

Comment: What command did you run to reset hard to your origin/master branch? Was it the `git reset --hard origin/master` command?

Comment: What branch were you on when you reset hard to your origin/master branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## "Syncing" between Branches

When you create and checkout a `new` branch, git brings along your current working directory and index. So at this point, `master` and `new` are still the same.

As you commit into `new` it will diverge from `master`. What you commit into `new` does not commit into `master`. They do not sync.

That said, if you have untracked files and you are making changes to them while on the `new` branch, those changes will remain available in the working directory whether you're on the `master` or `new` branch. Switching branches does not affect untracked files - they appear to be in sync.

That could explain why you experienced "syncing" between. Maybe the syncing was of untracked files. If after a dozen commits in `new` you checkout `master`, the working directory will still have any untracked files and their changes.

## Reset

When you run `reset`, git does not destroy your commits. Rather, it moves `HEAD` and your *current* branch to the commit that you specified. For example, if you made a dozen commits on the `new` branch and then - while still on the `new` branch - ran `git reset --hard origin/master`, your `new` branch and `HEAD` would now point at `origin/master`. Result: your working directory will contain only what was in `origin/master` and any untracked files might already be there. It would seem like you've lost all the commits that you made on `new`.

Importantly, you have not lost your commits.

You can view the commits using the reflog. Try this:

```
git reflog -10
```

This will list the last ten commits at which `HEAD` pointed. It will look something like this.

```
ok5073x HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to origin/master
fc5773d HEAD@{1}: commit: Some message
3b50d9f HEAD@{2}: commit: Some message
1ab5125 HEAD@{3}: commit: Some message
15bee3e HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to new
94ccc72 HEAD@{5}: commit: Some message
30276c1 HEAD@{6}: commit: Some message
15bee3e HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from new to master
36857b6 HEAD@{8}: commit: Some message
b9f0af5 HEAD@{9}: commit: Some message
17ue83e HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master to new
```

If you want to return to where you were before resetting and recover your commits, you can checkout one of your previous `HEAD` locations by running:

```
git checkout 3b50d9f
```

or

```
git checkout HEAD{1}
```

This might just save you.